# Showing $S^{-1}(M \otimes_{A} N) \cong S^{1}M \otimes_{S^{-1}A} S^{-1}N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

One of the propositions in Atiyah-MacDonald's Commutative Algebra states $$S^{-1}(M \otimes_{A} N) \cong S^{-1}M \otimes_{S^{-1}A} S^{-1}N.$$ The proof in the text states that one should use that $S^{-1}A \otimes_{A} M \cong S^{-1}M$ and properties of the tensor product.

I tried writing down the proof myself, but so far all I could show is the following

$$S^{1}(M \otimes_{A} N) \cong S^{-1}A \otimes_{A}( M \otimes_{A} N)$$

from where we have $$S^{-1}A \otimes_{A}( M \otimes_{A} N) \cong (S^{-1}A \otimes_{A} M )\otimes_{A} N \cong S^{-1}M \otimes_{A} N.$$

I must say that I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note if $A \to B$ is a ring extension and $M$ and $N$ are $A$-modules then
$$B\otimes_A(M \otimes_A N) \simeq (B \otimes_A M) \otimes_B (B \otimes_A N).$$
You can prove this fairly easily by just writing down obvious maps in both directions and showing that they're well defined and inverses.

Comment: By the way is the obvious map in the other direction, the one that sends $(b\otimes m, b' \otimes n) \mapsto (bb' \otimes ( m \otimes n))?$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.